# slicing a matrix into 2 arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript

Im trying to slice a matrix so that I can end up with to arrays.
So given the following matrix [[1,2],[3,4],[102,5]] is there a way to slice it so that I end up with [1,3,102] and [2,4,5] ?
Maybe its not a slice but something else?
Thanks

Comment: well I can't give it a range like slice(0,1) because that will just give me back the same array... I was thinking of using two for loops but was wondering if there was something that did this directly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [the `Array.reduce(...)` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), since functional programming is cool!

```javascript
function splitMatrix(matrix) {
  return matrix.reduce(function(acc, x) {
    acc[0].push(x[0]);
    acc[1].push(x[1]);
    return acc;
  }, [[],[]]);
}

splitMatrix([[1,2],[3,4],[102,5]]); // => [[1,3,102], [2,4,5]]
```

Comment: +1 I rushed to create an answer, that looked like the other two, but as someone who only works part time with javascript this is my first brush with reduce().

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4],[102,5]]
a1 = []
a2 = []
for(i = 0, i< a.length, i++){
    a1[i] = a[i][0]
    a2[i] = a[i][1]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var matrix = [[1,2],[3,4],[102,5]];
var arr1 = [];
var arr2 = [];

for(var i=0; i < matrix.length; i++){
    arr1.push(matrix[i][0];
    arr2.push(matrix[i][1];
}
```